# iOS 7 - didReceiveRemoteNotification: not triggering on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know that this question is tipical but I'm missing something and I don't kwon what is.

I have a simple application, in iOS 7. Using Xcode 6. I'm developing in objective-c.

I want to receive push notifications and update my app icon badge to (1) but I can't trigger the  didReceiveRemoteNotification method when the app is in background so I can't set the badge number. This is not my first app with push notifications and badges but I can't do it...

My code:

**- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
NSLog(@"RECEIVING NOTIFICATION");
```

When i'm on the app the badge is correctly setted and the log is printed, but if I'm in background mode the method is not triggered.

My payload APNS

```
{"aps":{"alert":"New push","sound":"default"}}
```

I want to set the badge manualy to 1. I don't need it on de payload.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You needn't set the badge by code, it will set automatic if you add a `badge` in your aps.

Comment: Ok, you were right...please answer my question and i will check your answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote notification will set the badge automatically according to the number of "badge" in aps.

For example:

`{"aps":{"alert":"New push","sound":"default","badge":1}}`

Comment: I am sending message to channel which have some large number of users in it. I don't have the unread message count of each user. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but it might help someone else.

You can trigger `- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` when your app is in background by following this two steps:

1. Set **Required background modes** to **App downloads content in response to push notifications** in your `Info.plist` file
2. Add `"content-available": 1` to your notification payload.

This will call `- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and allow you to handle notifications in background (i.e, refresh the content of your app, etc...).

Hope this helps!

Comment: for number 2 is there something similar in Firebase (if you are familiar with Firebase)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried Firebase yet. However, this should be iOS specific, not tied to your notifications service. I'd surprised if it didn't work with Firebase.